# How to resolve The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' exists in both

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

**How can I destinguish two namespaces in diferent Assemblyes? 
Or the only solution is to add aliases to namespaces?**

Here is a full error

```
The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' exists in both  
   'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll' 
and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll'
```

I have tried to move one of old projects from Visual Studio 2008 (it works here) to VS 2010. I am using **.net 3.5**

I can reference to older version of System.Web.Routing but I am confused why It works in VS 2008 and not in VS 2010

In both projects(same projects, but different versions of VS)

Reference System.Web.Routing reference to same same dll (with same path) `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Web.Routing.dll'

And reference to System.Web C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll

I have tried to call it like System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary but the error remains the same.

So documentation says thaht for

1. [Visual Studio 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary(v=vs.90).aspx) it is in Namespace:  System.Web.Routing
   Assembly:  System.Web.Routing (in System.Web.Routing.dll)
2. [Visual Studio 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary(v=vs.100).aspx) it is in Namespace:  System.Web.Routing
   Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)

If I remove reference for System.Web.Routing than I cant use classes in that namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be referencing an old assembly. At some point the RouteValueDictionary was moved into the System.Web.dll. Compare these:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary(v=vs.90).aspx

Check your references and also do a solution clean and rebuild.

Comment: Thans for sharing me links that I have alredy put in question.